# Workflow on already created objects

Tags: odoo

I have a module that creates a workflow on res.partner. Unfortunately, if I have some partners created when I install the module, this partners don't have any workflow associated.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Damián

Comment: can you give weokflow code here ??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a better way, but I think you could achieve this by including a [function tag](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_1.html#function-tag) in one of your module's data files. The function should be a function on your model class that creates a workflow entry for any partners that don't already have one.

You probably want to add `noupdate="1"` to the function tag so it doesn't run every time you upgrade the module.

Comment: First of all, sorry for the big delay on the reply. Yes, this looks like a good choice but, which are the instances of the workflow that I should create, I am looking at the models and everything seems very confusing. Which are the objects that I should create to achive this?

Comment: Here there is more clarification regarding this: https://answers.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+question/199722